# Derivative and second derivative

Tags: calculus

I've got some homework and having a problem to solve some of them.
Here are 3 of them where I need help, I need to differentiate them but no idea how I should do that.

1. Derivative of $e^{e^{e^{x}}}$
2. Derivative of $\ln(\ln(\ln x))$
3. Second derivative of $\ln(\ln x)$

Comment: pls show what you have done

Comment: What background do you have? Do you know the chain rule?

Comment: what do you mean with $$e^{e^{e^x}}$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: I guess it should be the way I edited it.

Comment: @Bernard That notation is ambiguous.  Is it $\left[\left[e^e\right]^e\right]^x$ or is it $e^{\left[\left[e^e\right]^x\right]}$?

Comment: It is $\mathrm e^{\left(\mathrm e^{(\mathrm e^x)}\right)}$.

Comment: You can use chain rule: $f(g(x))=f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$ where $f'(g(x))$ means that you evaluate the derivative of $f(x)$, then everytime there is an $x$ you write $g(x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the first derivative of #2 is given by $$f'(x)={\frac {1}{x\ln  \left( x \right) \ln  \left( \ln  \left( x \right) 
 \right) }}
$$ using the chain rule
and for #3 we get
$$f'(x)={\frac {1}{x\ln  \left( x \right) }}$$
and using the chanin rule and Quotient rule again:
$$f''(x)=-{\frac {1}{{x}^{2}\ln  \left( x \right) }}-{\frac {1}{{x}^{2} \left( 
\ln  \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}}}
$$ and check your answers

Comment: Omg you just saved my life! Thank you so much!

Comment: this is nice you've got only one!

Answer (score 1):

For the derivative of $f(x) = e^{e^{e^x}}$ you get, using the chain rule:

$f'(x) = e^{e^{e^x} + e^x + x}$.

Comment: What? It was that easy? Thanks a lot!